# I'm trying to make a loop of callback query handler and inline button

Tags: python, loops, callback, telegram

I'm trying to make a game bot on telegram, but I'm confused in callback query.
I have made a command named /start. When a user sends that command, the bot sends  two inline keyboard a and b.
If a gets pressed, the bot runs a code c = 10 - 2.
If b gets pressed, the bot runs a code c = 10 - 4.
I want to run this loop until the valua of c becomes Zero. i mean i want the bot to send this two inline button again and again until the value of c gets zero.
Any suggestions? I tried but it turned into a infinite loop.

```
c = 10
while c != 0:
    if query.data == a:
        c = 10 - 2
    elif query.data == b:
        c = 10 - 4
```

Comment: hi, the while loop condition has a lowercase `c` - is that defined or updated

Comment: hi, what do you want to do if C goes below zero. I mean if you receive "B", "B", "B". C will be -2 (10-4*3), so it won't be captured by your condition.

Comment: @jspcal sorry i did few typo error and im also bad in explaining but i edited it

Comment: @Thoughtful_monkey if c goes below zero then i want the code to be stopped right there.

Comment: Then try `c>0` instead of `c!=0`. Maybe that will fix your issue...